# OpenMP C and C++ cout/printf does not give the same output

Tags: openmp

I am a complete noob in OpenMP and just started by exploring some simple test script below.

```
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for
            for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
            std::cout<<i<<" "<<endl;
         //   printf("%d \n",i);
    }
}
```

I tried the C and C++ version and the C version seems to work fine whereas the C++ version gives me a wrong output.

Comment: Be more specific about what is output and what you expect (though I think I can surmise the latter in this case).

Answer (score 5):

Many implementations of `printf` acquire a lock to ensure that each `printf` call is not interrupted by other threads.

In contrast, `std::cout`'s overloaded `<<` operator means that (even with a lock) one thread's printing of `i` and `' '` and `'\n'` can be interleaved with another thread's output, because `std::cout<<i<<" "<<endl;` is translated to three `operator<<()` function calls by the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This is outdated but perhaps this could be still of help to anyone:

It's not really clear what you expect the output to be but be aware of:

1. Your variable "i" is possibly shared amongst threads. You have a race-condition for the contents of "i". One thread needs to wait for another when it wants to access "i". Further 1 thread can change "i" and another thread doesn't take note of it meaning it will output a wrong value.
2. The endl() flushes the memory after ending the line. If you use \n for newline the effect is similar but without the flush. And std is an object too so multiple threads race for std access. When the memory isn't flushed after every access you may experience interferences.

To make sure those are not related to your problems you could declare the "i" as private so every thread counts "i" itself. And you could play with flushing the memory at output so see if it has to do with the problem you experience.